# Extending navigation bar items the entire width of the box-shadow?

Tags: html, css

Here is what I'm working on:  [www.buymaengdakratom.com](http://www.buymaengdakratom.com)

I'm trying to have the navigation bar items extend the entire width of the box shadow, so that none of the white background of the box-shadow shows.

Here is the **CSS & HTML** I'm using http://jsfiddle.net/Abijah/DJsKk/

Comment: Couldn't you apply the box shadow to the `<li>`s instead of the `<ul>`?

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it. Remove the padding on the `<ul>` and set the display to table. Then on the list items, set their display to table-cell. Be sure to remove the float:left from the list items as well.

Added CSS:

```
ul {
    padding:0;
    display:table;
}
li {
    display:table-cell;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/DJsKk/1/)**.

This works in all modern browsers as well as IE8+.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

Set the `width: 970px;` and `padding: 0;` for `#appleNav`.

See it here: http://jsfiddle.net/DJsKk/2/.